# type annotations can only be used in typescript file. react native error

Tags: reactjs, react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fhj5n.png)

error: type annotations can only be used in a typescript file. react-native error.

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's a javascript file, and what you have there is a type annotation. You can't do that with javascript, instead what you should have is:

```
const App = () => {
    return (
    ...
```